# Shorthand for checking if array element is defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I'm trying to add together a bunch of elements in a decoded JSON array:

```
var jqXHR = $.getJSON("data.php", function(jsonData) {
    newItems      = jsonData['New']['count'] || 0;
    unsolvedItems = (jsonData['New']['count'] || 0)+
                    (jsonData['b']['count'] || 0)+
                    (jsonData['c']['count'] || 0)+
                    (jsonData['d']['count'] || 0)+
                    (jsonData['e']['count'] || 0)+
                    (jsonData['f']['count'] || 0)+
                    (jsonData['g']['count'] || 0);
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to check if the `['count']` element exists before I try and assign the value to something, using the shorthand explained [on this site](http://www.jquery4u.com/javascript/shorthand-javascript-techniques/), but the `|| 0` shorthand doesn't seem to be working. When `['New']` is not included in the JSON, I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'count' of undefined`.

Does this not work on arrays, or am I doing it wrong? If it doesn't work, what else could I do other than resorting to a separate if statement for every element I want to use?

Comment: The problem is that you can't get `jsonData['d']['count']` if `jsonData['d']` is `undefined`.

Comment: a way to do it will be `(jsonData['New']&&jsonData['New']['count']) || 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the pattern that I usually opt for:

`jsonData['b'] && jsonData['b']['count'] || 0`

Comment: Makes sense! How would this work with my example of adding elements together? Will that code just result in ['count'] or 0?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you can't get `jsonData['d']['count']` if `jsonData['d']` is `undefined`.

Your code is also full of repetitions. This kind of code is painful to maintain.

You could do it like this :

```
unsolvedItems = 0;
['New','b','c','d','e','f','g'].forEach(function(key){
    if (jsonData[key]) unsolvedItems += jsonData[key].count || 0;
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for that solution to the repetition! I was sure there was a better way to do it, but couldn't quite work it out.